# C# Passing parameters to stored procedure with EXEC query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to pass parameters from my program to Stored Procedure in EXEC format.Following is my code

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm = new FrmLogin();

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("File Name=E:\\Vivek\\License Manager\\License Manager\\login.udl");

            try
            {

                conn.Open();

                string user = username.Text;
                string pass = password.Text;

                string query = "EXEC dbo.checkuser"' + username.Text'" + " " + "'password.Text'"";

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Retrieve the return value

                string result = query.ToString();

                MessageBox.Show(result);



             }

             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
             }


              conn.Close();

         }
```

What should I write in string query=" "?,I am trying to pass username and password as parameters to the stored procedure and once the query executes and returns the result ,I will store it in another variable named result.Am I doing it the right way? I am new to C#

Please suggest,

Thanks

Comment: There is an hidden reason to explain why you need to use EXEC here?

Comment: By the way, if you are using SqlServer, you could also use a [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx). This might have better (faster) results than an OleDbCommand.

Answer (score 8):

Building command text with dynamically inserted segments from user input is very dangerous, and leaves you open to **SQL Injection**.

Below is a slight variation which *parameterizes* those strings. This approach is much safer.

```
string query = "dbo.checkuser";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
```

Note: This updated version sets up the command as a stored procedure, instead of plain text.

Comment: By the way, you didn't ask about this part, but I noticed that the code to retrieve the query output (`string result = query.ToString();`) is not going to work as expected. If you can describe what output you're expecting, we can help you with that part of it too. For example, if your stored proc is returning a single string value via a SELECT statement, then something like `string result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` might work.

Comment: Thanks Troy...is there any other technique apart from AddWithValues?

Comment: Yes, there are other alternatives listed in the official MSDN documentation for the [OleDbParameterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is what `cmd.Parameters` is an instance of).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("StoredPorcedureName",conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@user", username.Text);
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@pwd", password.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score -2):

That looks Okay at a glance except for your query string.  Change to:

```
string query = "EXEC dbo.checkuser '" + username.Text "', '" + password.Text + "'";
```

might work better.

### Edit

Yes, as per comments about SQL injection, Troy's answer is significantly better.

Just for completeness that can be possibly used in other situations, you can avoid SQL injection using this method by trying something like:

```
string query = "EXEC dbo.checkuser '" + username.Text.Replace("'", "''") "', '" + password.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

Comment: Prone to SQL injection.